# JPA entity id - primitive or object type (long or Long)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, types, entity, long-integer

**Should the ID of your Entity be *long* (primitive type) or *Long* (object type)?**

- The ID is the primary key of my table and is never 'null' in the database.
- My co-workers suggest to use an Object Type Long.
- Hibernate Reverse Engineering tool generates a primitive type long for id by default.

*What to choose? long or Long?*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COUNTRY")
public class CountryEntity implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "CURRENCY")
    private String currency;
    @Column(name = "PEOPLE")
    private Long people;
    @Column(name = "SIZE")
    private Long size;

    public CountryEntity() {
    }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I consider having Long is better, as it is more correct to check whether an entity has persistent identity by checking against the `null` value (in MySQL you can have an ID of value 0). Also some libraries like Spring base(d) on an ID of type Long (by default) in their logic. See this [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core/1.4.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/data/repository/core/support/AbstractEntityInformation.java#AbstractEntityInformation.isNew%28java.lang.Object%29) for an example.

The small advantage of the primitive: it takes a bit less space.

PS:Both are correct & supported according to the JPA specification and the answers to this question are somehow opinion-based.

Answer (score 11):

I'd prefer Long, for the simple reason that if you let the database generate ids for you (which you should), you can tell that a recently instantiated CountryEntity object is not yet persisted by checking for `id==null`. If you use long, then id will always have a non-null value (initially 0), which will change upon persisting the entity.

Comment: "which you should" - could you provide a reference for this reasoning (I agree somewhat but would prefer a source for this opinion)?

Comment: what if i make `Long id = -1L`?

Comment: Why would you? You can't make the id a constant, because as a primary key it must be unique and not null. While it's technically possible to use -1 as the "not yet persisted" value, what if some entity really has id=-1? You could use -1 as a crutch in those cases where you are forces to use long instead of Long, and then make sure -1 as a realy key can nver happen. But you'd have to be quite desperate to do this.

Comment: And what if the moon crashes into earth, what then? How would we survive? Yes, I am dead serious. "Let it fail" is actually a discipline, of sorts. We should be concerned with keeping up with good practices and a good design, staying away from nullable wrapper types is certainly one of those. Besides, we're supposed to write objects using the semantics of our programming language. That's why we use a JPA provider in the first place. My goal is to **not** hack my objects based on how they may/might/could/perhaps be used by a random (and arguably stupid) persistence provider.

Answer (score 1):

Use a String type for your entity id. Numeric types are intended for sequences or performing mathematical comparison and computations. If using a guid/uuid generator for id, you'll likely need to allow for non-numeric characters anyway (e.g. hyphens).

Comment: Strings are much less efficient within most (all?) database engines as a primary key than are integers or other numerics. This comes into play most frequently when doing joins to other tables. As anyone who has fought with MySQL's character set and collation challenges will tell you, this is asking for trouble. An integer or long is what it is (but never a float). There are valid reasons to use strings or guids or binary values, but they are not the general case.

Comment: @goosemanjack, the question/answer is referring to which data type to choose when representing an Id on a Java persistence Entity, not the underlying database column which might be of type BIGINT.