# Non-nullable ID with spring-data-mongodb in Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, entity, spring-data-mongodb, non-nullable

Is there any chance to make the `@Id` property non-nullable for Mongo-related entities in Kotlin?

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747891/kotlin-jpa-entity-id) there seems to be a solution for SQL by setting the ID initially to `0`. However, that seems like a hack, and seems to work only when using sequence generators.

My original intent is obviously to avoid nullable IDs like I have right now:

```
@Document class MyEntity( @Id var id: String? = null )
```

What I'd prefer if possible:

```
@Document class MyEntity( @Id val id: String )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lateinit`, but this may lead to a runtime error:

```
@Document
class File : Serializable {
    @Id
    lateinit var id: ObjectId
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
@Document(collection = COLLECTION_MY_ENTITY)
data class MyEntity @PersistenceConstructor constructor (
        @Id val id: String,
        @Field(FIELD_NAME) someField: String
)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How does this help me when I construct `MyEntity` by myself?

Comment: You shouldn't construct `MyEntity` by yourself. Store it through, say, `MongoTemplate` and use object representation when you load it from mongo