# JSP: NumberFormatException when joining 2 entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm trying to create custom queries in my hibernate and right now I'm using inner join.

This is my code:
Branch Repository:

```
@Query("select b from Branch b inner join User u ON b.branch_manager = u.id")
List<Branch> findAllBranchInfo();
```

Branch Service:

```
public List<Branch> getAllBranchInfo();
```

Branch Service Impl:

```
@Override
public List<Branch> getAllBranchInfo() {
    return (List<Branch>) branchRepository.findAllBranchInfo();
}
```

Branch Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/BranchTest", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView testBranch() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("test_branch");
    List<Branch> branchList = branchService.getAllBranchInfo();
    model.addObject("branchList",branchList);
    return model;
}
```

Branch Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="branch")
public class Branch {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long branch_id;

@Column(name="branch_name")
private String branch_name;

@Column(name="branch_manager")
private long branch_manager;

public long getBranch_id() {
    return branch_id;
}

public void setBranch_id(long branch_id) {
    this.branch_id = branch_id;
}

public String getBranch_name() {
    return branch_name;
}

public void setBranch_name(String branch_name) {
    this.branch_name = branch_name;
}

public long getBranch_manager() {
    return branch_manager;
}

public void setBranch_manager(long branch_manager) {
    this.branch_manager = branch_manager;
}

@OneToMany(targetEntity=User.class, mappedBy="branch",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<User> user;

public List<User> getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(List<User> user) {
    this.user = user;
}


}
```

And right now it's giving me this error:

```
Hibernate: select branch0_.branch_id as branch_i1_0_, branch0_.branch_manager as branch_m2_0_, branch0_.branch_name as branch_n3_0_ from branch branch0_ inner join user user1_ on (branch0_.branch_manager=user1_.id)
2018-09-25 07:46:04.544 ERROR 1708 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "first_name"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

I can't find it anywhere where I declared it as Integer.

This is my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${branchList }" var="branch">
    <tr>
        <td>${branch.branch_name}</td>
        <td>${branch.user.first_name}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Everytime I'm putting "${branch.user.branch_id}" it's giving me an error. Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you please post your Branch Model class ?

Comment: @sunkuet02 already added it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that one branch has many users. `branch.user` refers to a list of users, not one user. You should iterate to retrieve, for each user, his/her first name.

1.Rename the confusing method `getUser()` into `getUsers()` to better highlight the one-to-many relationship.

2.This is an attempt to fix your JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${branchList }" var="branch">
    <tr>
        <td>${branch.branch_name}</td>
        <c:forEach items="${branch.users}" var="user">
            <td>${user.first_name}</td>
        </c:forEach>         
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I guess that 
`{users.<n>}`, where `<n>` is an integer, refers to the `n`th element of the users list. This is why the JSP processor attempt to convert `first_name` to an integer when you have an expression like `{users.first_name}`

Comment: thank you so much. I've been asking the same question few days ago but you're the only one who solved my problem. thank youuu

Answer (score 0):

The recommended standard approach would be to change `long` to `Long`. See [jpa-entity-id-long-or-long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421735/jpa-entity-id-long-or-long) to know why?

and check the existing database values for the respected fields along with their type.

If above things are not solving the issue then drop the database and create it from start sometimes, because of incompatible data it happens.

Comment: on my model class?

Comment: yes instead of private long branch_id; use private Long branch_id; and curious to know private long branch_manager; is branch_manager is long?

Comment: yes because it's a foreign key of the id on my user table

Comment: I already tried dropping my table and changing it to "Long" but the error is still the same. Is my mapping wrong? I've been struggling to use join in query for days and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, if you want to do such things in your jsp, you should do something like this in your "Branch" model and your "User" model i guess?

```
...
@JoinColumn(name = "branch_manager", referencedColumnName = "branch_manager")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "User", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User branch_manager;
...
```

And the similar to your "User" model 
Then to your "Branch Repository" add JpaRepository, and I think you don't even need to use this method, just use a findAll method from your "Branch Controller".
And it should be OK!

*Hope it'll be helpfull, otherwise I missunderstood your question :)*